# Session variables with multiple instances on windows Azure

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm working on an MVC3 Project and SQL Azure database. when i deploy more than 1 instance i get some problems with the sessions variables.

To be more clear, i store the results of a table in a session variable and i pass the results to the model, the user can modify and manipulate the data until he clicks the  "save" button.

When the user clicks "Save" i obtain the new values from the model and pass them to the BLL and DAL layers for update the database.

I dont know if this is the right solution !! but the client won't hit the database on every data changing.

Help please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing is due to the fact the session data is stored locally on a server (this is called InProc by ASP.NET). When you're using multiple instances this data isn't shared between the instances. In order to accomplish this you have a couple of choices:

- Store the session data in a SQL Azure database.
- Store the session data in Azure's table storage.
- Store the session data in Azure's caching service (probably the fastest, but also the most expensive).

Here's some more info: http://acloudyplace.com/2012/02/managing-session-state-in-windows-azure-what-are-the-options/

Comment: Thank you! your answer helped me to understand why it does not work when i deploy more than one instance. If you have a better idea to manage data without using session variables I will be graceful

Comment: You can look at ViewBag to pass data from the controller to the view and ViewData for data that only has to be read once. If none of those can help you, session data is fine. As long as you store it in SQL Azure / Table storage that is.

Comment: The officially suggested way is to use AppFabric Cache as a session provider

Comment: Either Cache or SQL Azure are fine choices, especially since SQL Azure is fully supported since SDK v1.4 added the Universal Providers.

Comment: Good answer. What I did was to get rid of session usage as much as possible, this will make your app more scalable anyway. Then use Azure Blob storage for session state instead which was only 2 or 3 places in the app.

Comment: You can also enable sticky sessions  -> switch Session affinity on in azure. This might have some performance degradation.